# How to change font to custom font in vscode.dev

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

I want to change font in https://vscode.dev.

I’m using vscode tunnels.

What I’ve tried:

- Change font installed in remote machine. (doesn’t work)
- Change custom css (cannot install extension)

Is it even possible?

Comment: font of what? the editor area? the integrated terminal? the workbench?

Comment: anything. I can’t change the font except the provided ones

Comment: works just fine for me (I'm not using tunnels though). Ex. in settings.json in vscode.dev, `"editor.fontFamily": "'Times New Roman'"`. Does that work for you?

Comment: `Times New Roman` is provided font. For me, I want to use Iosevka font but it would not work.

Comment: did you install that font to your system yet?

Comment: Do you mean the machine running vscode.dev? If it is the remote machine, I did but if not,  I’m running in my ipad so I couldn’t install it.

Comment: the client machine.